# resetting raw_input within a while loop (python)

Tags: python, while-loop, raw-input

So I'm trying to get this engine to work, and I did, but it's broken my program. (from LPTHW)

I am basically trying to access a function where it gets an input from the user 11 times, if the user fails to guess the correct input, they die (in game) but my fix for sending the prompts from the engine to the functions, seemed to break the function where I get an input 11 times and just uses the same guess for all 11 inputs.

Here is the main engine

```
globvar = ' '

class Game(object):

    def __init__(self, start):
        self.quips = [
            "You died.  You kinda suck at this.",
            "Your mom would be proud. If she were smarter.",
            "Such a luser.",
            "I have a small puppy that's better at this."
        ]
        self.start = start


    def play(self):
        # next_room_name is taken from init argument start
        next_room_name = self.start

        while True:
            global globvar
            print "\n--------"
            # set variable room to get function from next_room_name
            room = getattr(self, next_room_name)

            print room.__doc__

            if room == self.laser_weapon_armory:
                prompt = raw_input("[keypad]> ")

            elif room == self.escape_pod:
                prompt = raw_input("[pod #]> ")
            else:
                prompt = raw_input("> ")
        globvar = prompt     
            # unpacks function from next_room_name into room
            next_room_name = room()
```

And here is the function im trying to get to work

```
def laser_weapon_armory(self):
        """
        You do a dive roll into the Weapon Armory, crouch and scan the room
        for more Gothons that might be hiding.  It's dead quiet, too quiet.
        You stand up and run to the far side of the room and find the
        neutron bomb in its container.  There's a keypad lock on the box
        and you need the code to get the bomb out.  If you get the code
        wrong 10 times then the lock closes forever and you can't
        get the bomb.  The code is 3 digits.
        """
        code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))

        guess = globvar
        guesses = 0

        while guess != code and guesses < 10:
            print "BZZZZEDDD!"
            guesses += 1
            guess = globvar

        if guess == code:
            print "The container clicks open and the seal breaks, letting gas out."
            print "You grab the neutron bomb and run as fast as you can to the"
            print "bridge where you must place it in the right spot."
            return 'the_bridge'
        else:
            print "The lock buzzes one last time and then you hear a sickening"
            print "melting sound as the mechanism is fused together."
            print "You decide to sit there, and finally the Gothons blow up the"
            print "ship from their ship and you die."
            return 'death'
```

And here is the output I get

```
--------

        You do a dive roll into the Weapon Armory, crouch and scan the room
        for more Gothons that might be hiding.  It's dead quiet, too quiet.
        You stand up and run to the far side of the room and find the
        neutron bomb in its container.  There's a keypad lock on the box
        and you need the code to get the bomb out.  If you get the code
        wrong 10 times then the lock closes forever and you can't
        get the bomb.  The code is 3 digits.

[keypad]> 124
BZZZZEDDD!
BZZZZEDDD!
BZZZZEDDD!
BZZZZEDDD!
BZZZZEDDD!
BZZZZEDDD!
BZZZZEDDD!
BZZZZEDDD!
BZZZZEDDD!
BZZZZEDDD!
The lock buzzes one last time and then you hear a sickening
melting sound as the mechanism is fused together.
You decide to sit there, and finally the Gothons blow up the
ship from their ship and you die.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this the kinda thing you're looking for? your question doesn't seem to be very clear

```
while guess != code and guesses < 10:
        guess = raw_input("BZZZZEDDD! - try again?")
        guesses += 1
        guess = ''
```

Comment: Yes this worked, it was hard to verbalize, but I basically wanted it to stop using the first variable from prompt over and over again, and this worked! thanks.

Comment: @lerugray No problem, I wasn't criticizing the question too much, I understand, it is hard to word something when you don't know the answer. It also doesn't help that I'm very tired :p hope your project turns out well, good luck